# Trying to Automate Advanced sharing settings

Tags: c#, powershell

I am in the process of creating a program in C# that will help my company automate configuration settings across out the box windows 10/11 devices.

I am trying to use C# to automate the configuration of Advanced Sharing Settings under the Network and Sharing Settings by using powershell scripts to make the changes.

I was able to successfully turn on Network Discovery as well as Turn on file and printer sharing for both the Private and Guest or Public Settings:

[Settings that where able to be updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf2zu.png)

However I am unable to find any powershell scripts to update the All Network settings:

[All Network settings that I also want to automate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b05B5.png)

I would need a way to automate:

1. Under Public Folder Sharing - Set the radio to Turn on Sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in public folders
2. Under File Sharing Connections - Set the radio to Enable file sharing for devices that use 40- or 56-bit encryption
3. Under Password protected sharing - set the radio to Turn off password protected sharing

My ultimate questions for this post is:

1. Is there a powershell script to change these tasks?
2. If there isn't is there a way someone with more experience can direct me towards achieving the goal of automating these tasks?

I would still consider myself a novice programmer - I am not too familiar with powershell itself and have been script-kittying the previous fields. My apologies if this post comes off as amateur.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have only done research as of this point. I am not too familiar with powershell, what is what I am trying to use to make changes.

Comment: Why are you using PowerShell for this instead of Group Policy?

Comment: How are you currently changing the profile-specific settings? WMI? `netsh.exe`?

Comment: @Dai - My company is very backwaters - we have no real systems administrator nor do we have server software. Using group policies is not something I can use as of this moment. I am trying to create an app that will allow us to do this.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen to be quite honest, I am not too sure how to answer that question. Like I mentioned, I mostly script kittyed and was able to use these two powershell scripts successfully: printer and sharing:
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "File And Printer Sharing" -Enabled True -Profile Any

Network Discovery:
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=”network discovery” new enable=yes      these two scripts worked, so I was wondering if there was a way to script out the other segments that I mention in my question